# Android phone can't access anything through VPN on my Windows PC

Tags: 2.1-eclair, samsung-galaxy-s, vpn

I have a Galaxy S (Android 2.1 Update 1), and a Windows 7 Pro machine configured to allow incoming connections (i.e the built-in PPTP VPN functionality).

I can establish a VPN connection to the laptop from the phone however I can't ping it or access a simple HTTP service running on 8081. Windows Firewall doesn't seem to be the issue as it doesn't work with it turned off either. It makes no difference if I use my house Wifi or disable that on the phone and connect via the phone's broadband connection.

I notice via IPCONFIG on the laptop that the subnet for the phone's RAS connection is 255.255.255.255 whereas the network is 255.255.255.0 - could this be a problem?

Comment: Do other devices connecting through this VPN work as expected?  The problem sounds to be with your VPN configuration on the laptop, which would put this question out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

It was a configuration issue on the program listening on port 80 on the laptop end.